# Copy and Paste file with Paste Javascript Listener In Firefox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, addeventlistener, copy-paste

I wonder why on Firefox copy and paste image file from the computer into browser with Javascript event listener doesn't work? But, when I tried it on chrome and edge, it worked perfectly.

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
        // event.preventDefault();
        console.log('event.items',event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile())
    });
</script>
```

See the code above, on chrome and edge, I got **file** data but in firefox, it's **undefined**

**firefox**:
[image]

**chrome**:
[image]

[Try on Code pen here](https://codepen.io/lamargt/pen/MWGQYmo?editors=1111)

Thanks a lot if anyone can figure it out why! Or is there any alternative that compatible with firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this behavior is on Windows and Linux. On macOS, I can take files from the `clipboardData` object in Firefox without any troubles. It's strange, and I had not found why this is so inside documentations from MDN.

But if your file is an image, and you try to paste it inside `contenteditable` `<div>`, Firefox will try to insert the `<img>` tag after the paste event.

So, for images, you can try to listen changes inside `<div>` and use base64 source from `src` attribute.

https://jsbin.com/qacicaj/6/edit?html,js,console,output